# Type error: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: typescript, next.js

I'm currently and moving some old websites to TypeScript.
One block of code keeps getting the error `Type error: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.` when I run build.

The block of code is:

```
useEffect(() => {
        let iframWrap = document.querySelectorAll<HTMLElement>('.video-wrapper iframe');
        iframWrap.forEach( (thing, key) => {
            const thingWidth : number = parseFloat( thing.getAttribute('width') );
            const thingHeight: number = parseFloat( thing.getAttribute('height') );
            let thingRatio : number = 1;
            if( typeof thingWidth === 'number' && typeof thingHeight === 'number'){
                thingRatio = parseFloat(thingWidth/thingHeight); 
            }else{
                thingRatio = 1;
            }
            thing.style.aspectRatio = thingRatio;
        })
    },
    []);
```

The error occurs on `thingRatio = parseFloat(thingWidth/thingHeight);` right where the division happens.

As you can see I've tried to assign number to every single variable I can in the function so I don't understand why type string is even coming up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, you should handle `thing.getAttribute('width')` in case it returns null

for the `thingRatio` you dont need to use parseFloat since `thingWidth` `thingHeight` are converted to numbers before.

here is the modified running code:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const iframeWrap = document.querySelectorAll<HTMLElement>('.video-wrapper iframe');

    iframeWrap.forEach((thing) => {
      const width = thing.getAttribute('width') || '0'; // Handle potential null values
      const height = thing.getAttribute('height') || '0'; // Provide a default value

      const thingWidth = parseFloat(width);
      const thingHeight = parseFloat(height);

      let thingRatio = 1;
      if (Number.isFinite(thingWidth) && Number.isFinite(thingHeight)) {
        thingRatio = thingWidth / thingHeight;
      }

      try {
        thing.style.aspectRatio = String(thingRatio); // Ensure aspectRatio is a string
      } catch (error) {
        console.warn('Error setting aspect ratio:', error); // Handle potential errors
      }
    });
  }, []);
```

Comment: This is it. This totally fixed it. Thanks so much for all your help making my code better. I'm still not 100% sure why the error happens or how this fixes it, but I'll definitely do a deep dive into this when I have the time.

Answer (score 0):

`style.aspectRatio` is of type string to which you are assigning a `number`. Convert the number to string before assigning.

```
thing.style.aspectRatio = thingRatio.toString();
```